# parameterising passport social login callback

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

I have the following callbacks for facebook and linkedin callbacks:

```
router.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', social.linkedin().authenticate('linkedin', {failureRedirect: '/web/login'}), function(req, res, next) { res.redirect(req.session.redirectURL); });
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', social.facebook().authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/web/login'}), function(req, res, next) { res.redirect(req.session.redirectURL); });
```

how do i parameterise them so that i can do away with one liner, say

```
// somehow get a service from the wildcard in the uri    
router.get('/auth/*/callback', social.service().authenticate(service, {failureRedirect: '/web/login'}), function(req, res, next) { res.redirect(req.session.redirectURL); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
router.get('/auth/:service/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    social[req.params.service]().authenticate(req.params.service, {failureRedirect : '/web/login'})(req, res, next);
}, function (req, res, next) {
    res.redirect(req.session.redirectURL);
});
```